# Contabilizar horas en PHP y SQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

necesito ayuda con este programa. El objetivo es calcular el tiempo en que los usuarios estuvieron trabajando, basándose en la `hora_entrada` y la `hora_salida`. He intentado usar `TIMEDIFF`, pero no funciona y espero que puedan ayudarme. Esta es la estructura de la tabla:

> La parte donde tengo problemas es aquí:

```
$consulta = 
    /*Se seleccionan los datos de todos los usuarios*/
    "(SELECT * FROM horas
    LEFT JOIN usuarios 
    ON horas.usuario=usuarios.usuario 
    WHERE usuarios.Activo_o_Inactivo='si';)
    UNION 
    (SELECT TIMEDIFF(horas.hora_salida, horas.hora_entrada) 
    as horas_totales FROM horas)
    ORDER BY horas.usuario;";
    if ($result = mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta)){
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo /*Se muestran los datos en la tabla ordenado de forma alfabetica*/
    "<tr>
        <td>".$row['usuario']."</td>
        <td>".$row['Fecha']."</td>
        <td>".$row['hora_entrada']."</td>
        <td>".$row['hora_salida']."</td>
        <td>".$row['horas_totales']."</td>
    </tr>";
```

> Esta es la estructura de la tabla: horas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Creo que hay problemas debido al `JOIN` y al `UNION`, pero no se si causen incompatibilidad.

Comment: `UNITE` ¿?  creo que eso no existe. ¿Podrías explicar mejor cómo están estructuradas las tablas y cómo se relacionan para poder ayudarte?

Comment: esa consulta funciona cuando la ejecutas directamente en la bd?

Comment: Perdon, era `UNION `, ya lo corregí pero aun así no funciona. La tabla horas tiene registrada la hora de entrada y salida de los usuarios, y el detalle es que el administrador vea cuantas horas han trabajado cada día

Comment: Y si, ya lo probé directo de la BDD y si funciona perfectamente

Comment: No creo que pueda funcionar esa consulta, ya que tienes un `union` de dos çonsultas con distinto número de campos. Puedes poner el resultado de esa consulta? Ademas Con ese modelo de tabla tienes un problema serio: que ocurre si un trabajador entra a las 22:00 de un día y sale a las 2:00 del siguiente?  Ha trabajado -20horas?

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que necesitas es que te calcule la diferencia entre las horas de un mismo día por registro , el query que debes ejecutar sería algo asi.

```
SELECT ID, Usuario, Fecha, hora_entrada, hora_salida,
     TIMEDIFF(horas.hora_salida, horas.hora_entrada)  as horas_totales
FROM horas
LEFT JOIN usuarios 
ON horas.usuario=usuarios.usuario 
WHERE usuarios.Activo_o_Inactivo='si';
```

Espero te sea util

Answer (score 0):

Para comprender un poco mejor, si necesitas obtener la cantidad de tiempo, que existe entre un rango de fechas, puedes obtenerlo con la función de sql, llamado "Datediff", está te representa esa cantidad en minutos, te anexo un ejemplo

```
Select DATEDIFF(minutos,Getdate(),Getdate()-1)
```

Comment: por que el menos 1? explicalo

Answer (score 0):

Perdón por tardarme en contestar, ya logre solucionar el problema y espero que también le sea útil esta solución a otras personas.

```
        $consulta = 
    /*Se seleccionan los datos de todos los usuarios*/
    "SELECT * FROM horas
    LEFT JOIN usuarios 
    ON horas.usuario=usuarios.usuario 
    WHERE usuarios.Activo_o_Inactivo='si'
    ORDER BY horas.usuario;";
    $HorasTotales=
    "SELECT TIMEDIFF(hora_salida,hora_entrada) 
    as horas_totales FROM horas;";
    if ($result = mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta) AND $Horas = mysqli_query($conexion,$HorasTotales)){
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) AND  $hrs=mysqli_fetch_assoc($Horas)){
```